# Don't open intercom messenger on load

Tags: chat, intercom

I am integrating Intercom into my website, but when a user loads the page, the chat window automatically opens up. I have gone through their documentation, adding things like `Intercom('hide')`, turning off and removing auto messaging, etc, but the messenger still opens up. I have reached out to their customer support (on their own chat app) and no one has responded back or reached out. Kind of bad UX to have it open without anyone clicking the chat button. Anyone know how to disable this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to App Settings > Messenger Settings section and blank Welcome Message:
[click to open an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1DSx.png)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is in one of their guides [Customize the Intercom Messenger (technical)](https://docs.intercom.com/configure-intercom-for-your-product-or-site/customize-the-intercom-messenger/customize-the-intercom-messenger-technical#show-the-intercom-messenger-to-selected-users-for-web-) rather than the technical documentation:

> 1. First, you’ll need to hide the Messenger for all of your customers. Just visit your Messenger settings and deselect the options for turning the Messenger on.
> 2. Next, you’ll need to think about which users you’d like to show the Messenger to (for example, your VIP customers).
> 3. Finally, add the hide_default_launcher attribute to your intercomSettings object on your site. The value of thehide_default_launcher attribute should be true or false, depending on if you want to hide or show the launcher.

So `hide_default_launcher` is the key.